# Extracting values between two same letter in java

Tags: java, regex

```
String data ="A486A946D48967E456F679B3425B234C847C
             A725A872D74985E45346F679B86705B234C2847C
Output should be in format like below:
-486
-3425
-847

-725
-86705
-2847
```

Above is the data from which I want to extract the values. They are in the same format, like: `A...A...D...E...F...B...B...C...C` where the dots represent numbers.

I want to extract the numbers between `A-A, B-B` and `C-C` like above. All those data are stored as string in a single line. I used a pattern matcher, but it didn't work. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Use regular expression

Comment: take two char variable prev and curr and check if they are same or not updating both variables if you encounter character if they are same get substring between them

Comment: Feel free for any queries

Comment: What pattern matcher did you use?

Comment: @Sumeet Singh. That is exactly what i wanted thak u so much.

Comment: @KrischalMahat You can upvote if you like my answer.

Comment: @Sumeet Singh all worked fine but at first it prints "-"  and in next line it prints 486. But others are printed in the correct way like(-3425 in next line and -847 in next line). How can i solve it?

Comment: @KrischalMahat I tested the code right now and it prints the -486 in one line only.

Comment: @KrischalMahat Are you sure you are using the exact same code.

Comment: @Sumeet Singh There was mistake in my code .I corrected it  just now. thank you for helping. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code.

```
char c1 = '\0';
char c2 = '\0';
String str = "";
for(int i = 0;i < data.length();++i)
{
 if(data.charAt(i) >= 65&&data.charAt(i) <= 90)
 {
  if(c1 == '\0')
   c1 = data.charAt(i);
  else if(c2 == '\0')
   c2 = data.charAt(i);
  if(c1 != '\0' && c2 != '\0')
   { 
    if(c1 == c2 && str.length() != 0)
     System.out.println("-"+str);
    str = "";
    c1 = c2;
    c2 = '\0';
   }
 }
 else 
  str += data.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: It's usually advised that you should use StringBuilder instead of String to build up a string by concatenation in a loop. (I.e. String str should be a StringBuidler).

Answer (score 6):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([A-Z])(\\d+)\\1");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(data);
while (m.find()) {
    String letter = m.group(1);
    String digits = m.group(2);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(digits);
    System.out.printf("- %s = %d%n", letter, n);
}
```

The pattern consists of:

- `([A-Z])` = group 1 with a capital letter
- `(\d+)` = group 2 with one or more digits
- `\1` = value of group 1

Comment: From this site only, I was advised not to use Pattern and Matcher for trivial problems, because they are damn slow than your code.

Comment: @SumeetSingh indeed I upvoted your answer, though StringBuilder should have been used. Here regex is fine, as there is no need for backtracking (undoing false half matches, loops of loops). And the solution is easier, less error prone, more understandable, maintainable. Quality counts too.

Comment: I used String, only cause the OP used it.